# Python - problem importing OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

If I run the following I see that OpenCV is installed:

```
$ pkg-config --modversion opencv
$ 2.4.10
```

I have it installed in a virtual environment but when I try to import the `cv2` module I get an error:

```
$ source ~/.profile
$ workon cv
$ python
>>> import cv2
<removed for brevity>
>>> ImportError: No module named cv2
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

The `pkg-config --modversion opencv` command only tells you your system has the *development libraries and headers* for OpenCV: the python bindings are in a separate package called  `python-opencv`. You can install that from the Software Center, or from a terminal using

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue. Tried different things. But finally

```
conda install opencv
```

solved the issue for me.

Comment: +1 for likely relevant answer. Quick googling found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23119413) on Stack Overflow. This method reportedly works in Ubuntu 14.04, but not with Python 3.4.